# how to log the request information using logback for very method annotated with @RequestMapping in a spring mvc controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, logback

Right now I am using logback for logging in one spring mvc project. And I need to log every request against the controller. There are quite a lot of methods in the controller and they are annotated with the @RequestMapping. I am thinking if there is a way to make the log automatically with Aspectj or something which is already built-in in SpringMVC framework. Someone who knows it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "accounts/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Collection<DTOWithAccountInfo> getAccounts(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    //todo:log the request info for
  }
```

so I want to log the request info like URI for example for very @RequestMapping annotated method in spring mvc, maybe AOP is a good point to start with?

Comment: Please provide some sample code as a basis of discussion. I think I can help you but I do not like to guess what exactly you might want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have edit the question.